# Bridge Wi-Fi through router > Galaxy S3 > desktop Windows

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, windows, wifi-hotspot

I'm usually hooked up to a wall Ethernet port on my PC, but I'm away for a little over a week now and I only have access to Wi-Fi. The signal is just *barely* out of range. I can use Skype and whatnot with my poor connection, but can't browse the web.

I set up a mobile hotspot on my S3 and have a speed of roughly 5 Mbps (download), so that's wonderful, but I figure I'll run out of data quickly (I've already used 40 MB in the past minute) -- I'm unable to connect to Wi-Fi while my phone is a hotspot, so I don't believe I can continue using the hotspot without running out of data if it's going solely off of my data plan.

My phone has a better wireless card than my desktop, and can browse the web, etc perfectly -- since my phone has such a good connection, I figure I can bridge the connection from it to my PC and not have to use up my data plan. While researching why I couldn't use Wi-Fi and the hotspot at the same time, it turned out that since my phone only had one Wi-Fi antenna it couldn't handle both of them at the same time. I'm not sure if bridging the connection from my phone to my computer would require more than one -- maybe it will, maybe it won't. Is this possible?

Windows 7
Non - rooted Galaxy S3
Android Version 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, connect your phone to your computer via a good quality usb data cable.

Disable your computers wifi, connect your phone to your wifi.

Go to settings on your phone and enable 'Usb-tethering" (it will be in the same place as wifi tethering was. Wait a couple of seconds for your computer to recognise it, and you're done